# I tried to pass value from ajax to codeigniter controller using post method but it is returning void

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I tried to store ajax value in codeigniter controller variable using post method I used $this->input->post method in the controller but the variable in the controller is not getting the ajax value, the variable is returning as null, help me to find a solution for this error Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

View:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md edit-pdt" data-pid="<?php echo $row->product_id;?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
```

Controller:

```php
public function displayprodt()
    {
        $pid= $this->input->get('pid');
        $data = array(
            'title' => "Edit Product",
            'result' => $this->ProductModel->displayprodt($pid)
        );
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('navbar');
        $this->load->view('sidebar');
        $this->load->view('editproduct',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

JQuery:

```js
$('.edit-pdt').click(function(){
        var base_url = $("#base_url").val();
        var pid = $(this).attr("data-pid");
        alert(pid);
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: base_url+"index.php/Product/displayprodt",
           data: ({pid: pid}),
           success: function(response) {
             location.href = base_url+"index.php/product/displayprodt";
           }
        });
  });
```

Model:

```php
public function displayprodt($pid){
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("todaysdeal_products");
        $this->db->where("product_id",$pid);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: `alert(base_url );` then see whats are acutually getting

Comment: you fetching data from URL in controller so you need to send in url as `base_url+"index.php/Product/displayprodt"+pid `

Comment: `variable is returning as null` which one?

Comment: $pid variable is returning as null.

Comment: try print_r($_POST) or in XHR tab of network , check if you get something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is your page redirects whatever returned from first request.  please try replacing `location.href = base_url+"index.php/product/displayprodt";` with `console.log(response);`  or `alert(response);`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$this->input->post('pid')` then you have to use POST in ajax.

change

```
1: type: "GET", to type: "POST",
2: data: ({pid: pid}), to data: {pid: pid},
```

Comment: have you added jquery.min

Comment: change in controller : $pid= $this->input->get('pid'); to $pid= $this->input->post('pid');

Comment: Yes, I have added

Comment: Echo some thing in controller & remove redirection from success & check in console. you can also check network  tab from inspect if nothing is there then again call ajax & click on network ajax call & check what is the error.

Comment: I used var_dump($pid); die(); function in the controller it is returning null ajax call is working fine the problem is in getting the value in controller

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create controller to control ajax data i will give you example :

**Controller**

```
public function displayprodt()
{
      $pid = $this->input->post('pid',true);

           $data=array(
                'error' =>false,
                'title' => 'Edit Product',
                'result' => $this->ProductModel->displayprodt($pid),
            );


      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($data ,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function displayprodt($pid){
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("todaysdeal_products");
        $this->db->where("product_id",$pid);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.edit-pdt').click(function(){
        var base_url = $("#base_url").val();
        var pid = $(this).attr("data-pid");
        alert(pid);
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: base_url+"index.php/Api/displayprodt",
           data: ({pid: pid}),
           dataType: "JSON",
           success: function(response) {
             location.href = base_url+"index.php/product/displayprodt"; // or any url you want redirect.
           }
        });
  });
```

I hope you find solution :')